# WordPress - How to correctly handle custom profile fields update

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding some custom fields to the wordpress user profile. I'm getting the fields from user_meta table and I'm able to see them using the `get_the_author_meta()` function.
I need now to save them but into the codex it's not clear how to proceed because the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile_update/) will say that wordpress will empty a `$_POST` field if the name of it it's the same of the meta key.

I have this code at the moment, every example I've found will not consider what into the codex is writed. How I will save correctly the fields, do I need to use a different name for input fields? Do I need to pass the user id or it will be recognized automatically from wordpress?

```php
    function save_profile_extra_fields( $user )
    {
        //Check if user can manage options
        if( !current_user_can('manage_options') ){
            return;
        }
        // Saving custom fields
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'my_custom_field', $_POST['my_custom_field'] );
    }
    add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'save_profile_extra_fields');
```

Comment: The `edit_user_profile_update` takes a integer value in it's arguments.

Comment: I have tride passing `$user_id` like many examples and seems not working, it will save only the default profile fields, not the custom one I have.

Comment: How are you adding your custom fields. I assume on the `edit_user_profile` hook?

Comment: I had a typo error that I've discovered after used the `error_log()` function of php. Thak you for the help